# pandas: sort each column individually

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks something like this, only much larger.

```
d = {'Col_1' : pd.Series(['A', 'B']),
 'Col_2' : pd.Series(['B', 'A', 'C']),
 'Col_3' : pd.Series(['B', 'A']),
 'Col_4' : pd.Series(['C', 'A', 'B', 'D']),
 'Col_5' : pd.Series(['A', 'C']),}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5
  A      B      B      C      A
  B      A      A      A      C
  NaN    C      NaN    B      NaN
  NaN    NaN    NaN    D      NaN
```

First, I'm trying to sort each column individually. I've tried playing around with something like: `df.sort([lambda x: x in df.columns], axis=1, ascending=True, inplace=True)` however have only ended up with errors. How do I sort each column individually to end up with something like:

```
Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5
  A      A      A      A      A
  B      B      B      B      C
  NaN    C      NaN    C      NaN
  NaN    NaN    NaN    D      NaN
```

Second, I'm looking to concatenate the rows within the columns

```
 df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.sum(axis=0),columns=['Concatenation']).T])
```

I can combine everything with the line above after replacing np.nan with '', but the result comes out smashed ('AB') together and would require an additional step to clean (into something like 'A:B').

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> pandas.concat([df[col].order().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
11:      0    1    2  3    4
0    A    A    A  A    A
1    B    B    B  B    C
2  NaN    C  NaN  C  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  D  NaN

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

However, what you're doing is somewhat strange.  DataFrames aren't just collections of unrelated columns.  In a DataFrame, each *row* represents a record, so the value in one column is semantically linked to the values in other columns in that same row.  By sorting the columns independently, you're discarding this information, so the rows are now meaningless.  That's why the `reset_index` is needed in my example.  Also, because of this, there's no way to do this in-place, which your example suggests you want.

Comment: It is a little strange. Each column represents a conversation. Sometimes there are two people, sometimes 3, sometimes many more. The order of who is listed in the conversation is not relevant, since A:B == B:A. The problem could easily be transposed, but needs to be horizontal for the final output.

Comment: Rather than drop the index, I think you can/should just use the `.values`.

Answer (score 15):

[`pandas.Series.order` is deprecated since pandas=0.17.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.Series.order.html) Instead, use `sort_values` as follows:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].sort_values(ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your data were numeric you could use Numpy's sort function:

```
df[:] = np.sort(df.values)
```

But this fails in your case because it can't handle a mixture of floats and strings.

Here's one workaround:

```
df[:] = np.sort(df.fillna('\xff\xff\xff').values)
df = df.replace('\xff\xff\xff', np.nan)
```

I just replace the NaNs with a string of characters with ASCII value 255 so that they will almost certainly be at the end after the sort.  Then I replace them with NaNs.

Output:

```
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5
0     A     A     B     B     C
1     A     A     A     B     C
2     B     C   NaN   NaN   NaN
3     D   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True), axis=0)
```

(Thanks @BrenBarn for the remark on `reset_index`.)

Using @Andy Hayden's comment about `values` instead of `reset_index` leads to

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().values, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is any better, but here are a couple other ways to do it.

```
 pd.DataFrame({key: sorted(value.values(), reverse=True) \
    for key, value in df.to_dict().iteritems()})

 pd.DataFrame({key: sorted(values, reverse=True) \
    for key, values in df.transpose().iterrows()})
```