# pandas- adding a series to a dataframe causes NaN values to appear

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
d = {'Col_1' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']),
     'Col_2' : pd.Series(['B', 'C', 'B', 'D']),
     'Col_3' : pd.Series([np.nan, 'D', 'C', np.nan]),
     'Col_4' : pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 'D', np.nan]),
     'Col_5' : pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 'E', np.nan]),}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5
  A      B      NaN    NaN    NaN
  A      C      D      NaN    NaN
  A      B      C      D      E
  B      D      NaN    NaN    NaN
```

My Goal is to end up with something along the lines of:

```
Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5  ConCat
  A      B      NaN    NaN    NaN    A:B
  A      C      D      NaN    NaN    A:C:D
  A      B      C      D      E      A:B:C:D:E
  B      D      NaN    NaN    NaN    B:D
```

I've successfully created a dataframe that looks like the desired output from:

```
rows = df.values
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([':'.join(word for word in rows if word is not np.nan) for rows in rows])

    0
0  A:B
1  A:C:D
2  A:B:C:D:E
3  B:D
```

But now when I attempt to place it into the original dataframe, I get:

```
df['concatenated'] = df_1

Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5  concatenated
  A      B      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
  A      C      D      NaN    NaN    NaN
  A      B      C      D      E      NaN
  B      D      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

What's strange is that when creating a simplified example, it works as expected. Below if the full code of what I'm doing. The original data comes to me transposed from what the original dataframe above looks like.

```
df_caregiver_type = pd.concat([df_caregiver_type[col].order().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df_caregiver_type], axis=1, ignore_index=False).T
df_caregiver_type.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Col_' + str(x), inplace=True)
rows = df_caregiver_type.values
df_caregiver_type1 = pd.DataFrame([':'.join(word for word in rows if word is not np.nan) for rows in rows])
df_caregiver_type['concatenated'] = df_caregiver_type1
df_caregiver_type = df_caregiver_type.T
df_caregiver_type
```

*Update*
I'm thinking I'm getting an error due to the first row of the full code. It's from a separate, but related question: [pandas: sort each column individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171511/pandas-sort-each-column-individually)

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with the first solution in `0.13.1`. I assume the `'np.nan'` should be `np.nan` in dictionary `d`, right?

Comment: That is correct. I've updated the dictionary.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For your full dataset, change the last step from `df['concatenated'] = df_1` to `df['concatenated'] = df_1.values` will solve the issue, I think it a bug and I am very sure I have seen it in SO before.

Or just: `df['concatenated'] = [':'.join(word for word in row if word is not np.nan) for row in rows]`

Comment: Adding the `.values` got it to successfully create the new column

Comment: It is strange bug, not affecting small datasets, only affecting big ones. :<

Comment: It's certainly strange. The full data set is a little over 1700 rows/18columns after the transpose. Caused me to smack my head against my head against the desk for half a day...

Comment: what a relief to find out I am not crazy and it is indeed some strange bug. Thank you for the answer. I just also did a lot of the head smacking. Extremely weird bug. And my dataframe is `125 x 17` only btw

Comment: I believe this happen only with DIFFERENT INDEXES

Comment: Just wasted some hours of my life with this, thanks for the answer. In my case I was creating a new column with Series(np.where ..., name='colname'), either the .values or removing that Series() solved for me (20K rows)

Comment: something to do with indices, as Federico noted...

Comment: @FedericoDorato I agree. Non-matching indices will cause problem as described by OP. Matching the index of the Series to the DataFrame before adding the Series as a column: `pandas.Series.set_axis(df.index, inplace=True)` before `df["Series"] = pd.DataFrame(Series)`.

Comment: Had the same problem with a small Series (400 entries). `.values` saved the day. Strange behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {'Col_1' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']),
...      'Col_2' : pd.Series(['B', 'C', 'B', 'D']),
...      'Col_3' : pd.Series([np.nan, 'D', 'C', np.nan]),
...      'Col_4' : pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 'D', np.nan]),
...      'Col_5' : pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 'E', np.nan]),}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> 
>>> rows = df.values
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame([':'.join(word for word in rows if word is not np.nan) for rows in rows])
>>> 
>>> df['concatenated'] = df_1[0]
>>> df
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5 concatenated
0     A     B   NaN   NaN   NaN          A:B
1     A     C     D   NaN   NaN        A:C:D
2     A     B     C     D     E    A:B:C:D:E
3     B     D   NaN   NaN   NaN          B:D
>>>
```

Comment: Adding the `[0]` to the end of `df_caregiver_type1` still produces the error I'm experiencing in the full data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = df.join(df_1)
>>> df = df.rename(columns = {0:'concatenated'})
```

Comment: They have different indexes, and no overlapping columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means.  The above lines produce your desired output.

Comment: The example is simplified- I'm trying to show what I'm doing with the full code block below- which has a multiindex. When I use .join with the full code set, I get `ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names`

Comment: This answer is being flagged as low quality because it is code only.  Could you please include an explanation as to why or how this solves the question?

Comment: @Mr.Llama not sure how this is 'low quality'.  It's pretty self explanatory; type in my answer and it produces the output.  Then DataSwede explained he had a more general case that it didn't work on.   Trolling stackoverflow to play answer police is about as unconstructive and 'low quality' as it gets.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 - I wasn't the one that flagged the answer.  The answer itself was automatically flagged by Stack Overflow and showed up in the review pool because it was a code only answer.  I was just giving you a heads up that adding additional information to the post would prevent automatic flagging.