# Pandas. Cannot sort by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Edited for clarity:

I have a dataframe in the following format

```
i    col1         col2  col3
0    00:00:00,1   10    1.7
1    00:00:00,2   10    1.5
2    00:00:00,3   50    4.6
3    00:00:00,4   30    3.4
4    00:00:00,5   20    5.6
5    00:00:00,6   50    1.8
6    00:00:00,9   20    1.9

...
```

That I'm trying to sort like this

```
 i    col1         col2  col3
0    00:00:00,1   10    1.7
1    00:00:00,2   10    1.5
4    00:00:00,5   20    5.6
3    00:00:00,9   20    1.9
4    00:00:00,4   30    3.4
5    00:00:00,3   50    4.6
6    00:00:00,6   50    1.8

...
```

I've tried `df = df.sort_values(by = ['col1', 'col2']` which only works on col1.
I understand that it may have something to do with the values being 'strings', but I can't seem to find a workaround for it.

Comment: do you want to [sort col2 independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171511/pandas-sort-each-column-individually) of the rest or is your example incorrect?

Comment: @mozway My example was incorrect. I updated to hopefully be more clear. Basically I'm trying to sort values group wise.

Comment: so `df.sort_values(by=['col2', 'col1'])`? can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(by = ['col2', 'col1']
```

Gave the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If need sort each column independently use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
c = ['col1','col2']
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().to_numpy())
#alternative
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().tolist())
print (df)
   i        col1  col2
0  0  00:00:00,1    10
1  1  00:00:01,5    20
2  2  00:00:10,0    30
3  3  00:01:00,1    40
4  5  01:00:00,0    50
```