# How to merge two columns and re-arrange data in a specific order?

Tags: python, pandas

New to python. I need to merge CA1 with CA2 and CB1 with CB2 and re-arrange the data with a specific order shown in the example.
Dataset

|  | CA1 | CB1 | CA2 | CB2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1.1 | B | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 1.3 | D | 1.4 |
| 3 | E | 1.5 | F | 1.6 |
| 4 | G | 1.7 | H | 1.8 |

Needed as

|  | CA1 | CB1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1.1 |
| 2 | B | 1.2 |
| 3 | C | 1.3 |
| 4 | D | 1.4 |
| 5 | E | 1.5 |
| 6 | F | 1.6 |
| 7 | G | 1.7 |
| 8 | H | 1.8 |

Comment: rearrange CA1 and CB1 separately? Or only CA1 for example, and drag CB1 along with it

Comment: Hi, two separate columns as shown in the example. CA1 with str value and CB2 with numerical.

Comment: how many such columns?

Comment: Two columns. Data in the CA2 and CB2 needs to move to CA1 and CB2 in the particular order shown in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stack the column pairs and create DataFrame out of them:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({'CA1': df[['CA1', 'CA2']].stack().values,
              'CB1': df[['CB1', 'CB2']].stack().values})
  CA1  CB1
0   A  1.1
1   B  1.2
2   C  1.3
3   D  1.4
4   E  1.5
5   F  1.6
6   G  1.7
7   H  1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your dataframe into 2 parts, and concatenate them vertically. Then [sort columns individually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24171511/14627505):

```py
first = df[['CA1', 'CB1']]
second = df[['CA2', 'CB2']].set_axis(['CA1', 'CB1'], axis=1)

result = pd.concat([first, second], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
for col in result:
    result[col] = result[col].sort_values(ignore_index=True)
```

**Result:**

```py
  CA1  CB1
0   A  1.1
1   B  1.2
2   C  1.3
3   D  1.4
4   E  1.5
5   F  1.6
6   G  1.7
7   H  1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Below Code using - **Numpy**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'CA1':['A','C','E','G'],'CB1':[1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7],'CA2':['B','D','F','H'], 'CB2':[1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8]})

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df[['CA1','CB1']].values,df[['CA2','CB2']].values]), columns=['CA1','CB1']).sort_values('CA1')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('CA1', 'CB1'), 
    names_pattern = ['CA', 'CB'], 
    sort_by_appearance=True)

  CA1  CB1
0   A  1.1
1   B  1.2
2   C  1.3
3   D  1.4
4   E  1.5
5   F  1.6
6   G  1.7
7   H  1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
### Assuming your dataframe is called df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{
    'CA1': 'A', 'CB1': 1.1, 'CA2': 'B', 'CB2': 1.2},
    {'CA1': 'C', 'CB1': 1.3, 'CA2': 'D', 'CB2': 1.4},
    {'CA1': 'E', 'CB1': 1.5, 'CA2': 'F', 'CB2': 1.6},
    {'CA1': 'G', 'CB1': 1.7, 'CA2': 'H', 'CB2': 1.8}])
# Make new dataframe with extra columns and rename the headers to match
df2 = df[['CA2', 'CB2']].rename(columns={
    'CA2': 'CA1', 'CB2': 'CB1'}
    )
# Drop the extra columns from your initial dataframe
df.drop(columns=['CA2','CB2'], inplace=True)
# Concat the dataframes
# ignore index so your index continues naturally rather than resetting
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
### Sort your dataframe by CA1 first, then CB1
df.sort_values(by=['CA1', 'CB1'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```