# sort each row in a dataframe alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6   ...   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
0      NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  NaN  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN
2      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  TUR  ...  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  HEX  HEX  HEX
3      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ...  HEX  NaN  NaN  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN
4      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  TUR  ...  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  HEX  HEX  HEX
    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
32607  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32608  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32609  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32610  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32611  NaN  NaN  NaN  TUR  NaN  ACP  HEX  ...  NaN  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I want to sort each row alphabetically, i.e., pushing all `NaN` to the right and bringing all strings to the left.

Comment: I can also do it if all `NaN`s are "None", if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort using the underlying numpy array after temporarily filling the NaNs.

Here I used the `DEL` character as filler as it sorts after the ASCII letters but you can use anything you want that is larger. Alternatively use `lexsort` with the array of `df.isna()` as final sorting key.

```
c = '\x7f'

out = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.fillna(c).to_numpy()),
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns
                  ).replace(c, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0      ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1      ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  TUR NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  TUR  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32607  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32608  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32609  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32610  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32611  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

If you just want to push the non-NaNs to the left:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
b = df.isna().to_numpy()

out = pd.DataFrame(a[np.arange(len(a))[:, None], np.argsort(b)],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns
                  )
```

Output:

```
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
0      TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      TUR  TUR  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3      TUR  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4      TUR  TUR  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32607  TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32608  TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32609  TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32610  TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
32611  TUR  ACP  HEX  HEX  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    ss1=ss.sort_values(na_position='last')
    ss1.index=ss.index
    return ss1
df1.apply(function1,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0      ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1      ACP  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  TUR NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4      HEX  HEX  HEX  HEX  TUR  TUR  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32607  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32608  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32609  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32610  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
32611  ACP  HEX  HEX  TUR  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by transposing the DataFrame so each row is a Series, sorting each column (row Series) individually, and then rebuilding the DataFrame

```py
# transpose the DataFrame and keep a reference
df_T = df.T

# iterate by-columns (originally rows)
data = {}
for row_index in df_T:
    data[row_index] = df_T[row_index].sort_values(ignore_index=True)

# unpack transposed, sorted data as rows
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")

# fix the column names if they're not really sequential numbers
#df_sorted.columns = df.columns  # or df_T.index if re-using df name already
```

Independent column sort cribbed from [pandas: sort each column individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171511/pandas-sort-each-column-individually)